# Retrieve subString from string in java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I  am receiving exception message in java, I need exception code of exception message.

Example in below string i need to extract only **535-5.7.8** as output

```
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q74sm13073133pfd.134 - gsmtp
```

below is code

```
  public class mailDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
    //get Session

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Transport transport;
    while (true) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Email Address ");
        String userName=scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter password ");
        String passwd=scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", userName,
                    passwd);
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("SuccessFull");
            //Authentication success
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Session Failed ");
      //  e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you have? This require a [mcve]

Comment: i need regexp pattern , so i can extract the error code

Comment: Good luck with that then, you need to show some effort to expect some help

Comment: now complete code is available let me know if any other way to retrieve exception code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a regex problem... have you check what is a [mcve] ?

Comment: Do you need the code of each line or only the first one?

Comment: only for first line

Comment: Where does the exception is located/written? Not including the only catch exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `String.split(" ")[0]` to recieve the error code.

Comment: Thanks , that is expected